# How to Databind Multiple Layers of Collections?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-phone-7, data-binding, wpftoolkit

Suppose:

```
<manufacturer name="A">
  <phone>1</phone>
  <phone>2</phone>
</manufacturer>
<manufacturer name="B">
  <phone>3</phone>
  <phone>4</phone>
</manufacturer>
```

Is there a neat way of databinding it to an ItemsSource so that it displays all the phones as 1, 2, 3, 4? If I just generate it using Expression Blend, it gives

```
DataContext="{Binding manufacturerCollection[0].phoneCollection}"
```

which only gives 1, 2. Better yet, is there a way to group them in WP7 Silverlight Toolkit's ListPicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of binding to manufacturerCollection, you can create a new property and use Linq to 'flatten' your collection:

```
public IEnumerable<Phone> Phones { get { return manufacturerCollection.SelectMany(m => m.phoneCollection); }}
```

(replace 'Phone' by the type of the objects stored in phoneCollection)